# How to convert string to property JSX.Element - react

Tags: reactjs

I try to convert string property to property JSX.Element.
this compenent appears once as `birthDate1` and once appears twice like `birthDate1` and `birthDate2` so we defined 2 such elements:

```
import { ValidationSchema } from './Context'

export const initialValues: ValidationSchema = {
  sumChildren: {
    value: '',
    error: '',
    validate: 'number'
  },
  maritalStatus: {
    value: 'single',
    error: '',
    validate: 'select'
  },
  immigrationDate1: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
  immigrationDate2: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
  birthDate1: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
  birthDate2: {
    value: '',
    error: ''
  },
```

But I can not convert the text to the real value.

The component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext } from 'react'
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import { AppContext } from '../Context'

export default function SecondStep({name}:SecondProps) {
  const { formValues, handleChange, handleBack, handleNext, variant, margin } = useContext(AppContext)
  const { birthDate1, immigrationDate1, serviceDate1, endServiceDate1,birthDate2, immigrationDate2, serviceDate2, endServiceDate2  } = formValues


  if(name ==='2')
    birthDate2.required=true
  


  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>  
  <Grid item xs={12}>
  <TextField
    variant={variant}
    margin={margin}
    fullWidth
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
    label='Birth Date'
    name={`birthDate${name}`}
    type='date'
    onChange={handleChange}
    required={Boolean(true)}
    defaultValue={Parser(`birthDate${name}.value`)} --this not work
  />
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <TextField
    variant={variant}
    margin={margin}
    fullWidth
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
    label='Immigration Date'
    name={`immigrationDate${name}`}
    type='date'
    defaultValue={Parser(`immigrationDate${name}.value`)}
    onChange={handleChange}
    required={Boolean(false)}
  />
</Grid>
{(Boolean(`immigrationDate${name}.value`) === true) && --this not work
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <TextField
    variant={variant}
    margin={margin}
    fullWidth
    InputLabelProps={{
      shrink: true
    }}
    label='Service Date'
    name={`serviceDate${name}`}
    type='date'
    defaultValue={Parser(`serviceDate${name}.value`)}
    onChange={handleChange}
    required={Boolean(false)}
  />
</Grid>
}
      </Grid>
 
    </>
  )
}
```

Please, I need help, I try many ways and nothing works good for me.

Comment: if add sample in https://codesandbox.io/ better for help